# The program RedCross.java is supposed to display a red cross on a white background. It's only making the top left of the cross

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I don't know what makes it print the whole cross, it only prints the top left corner

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RedCross extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(xCenter, yCenter, 10, 50);
        g.fillRect(xCenter, yCenter, 50, 10);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      JFrame window = new JFrame("Red Cross");
      window.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 200);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      RedCross panel = new RedCross();
      panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      Container c = window.getContentPane();
      c.add(panel);
      window.setVisible(true);
   }    
}
```

Comment: You appear to be drawing the lines of your cross from the center, and going outwards. If this is how you want to draw it, you need all 4 "arms" of the cross, instead of the two you have in your code.

Comment: What else have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be drawing the lines of your cross from the center, and going outwards. If this is how you want to draw it, you need all 4 "arms" of the cross, instead of the two you have in your code.

You could draw the four "arms" individually:

```
    g.fillRect(xCenter-5, yCenter, 10, 50);
    g.fillRect(xCenter-5, yCenter-50, 10, yCenter);
    g.fillRect(xCenter-50, yCenter-5, 50, 10);
    g.fillRect(xCenter, yCenter-5, 50, 10);
```

This will center a red cross, 100px wide and 100px tall.

Comment: +1 Please consider add your previous comment to the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your `paintComponent()` method with something like this -

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int strokeSize = getWidth() / 10;
    if (getHeight() / 10 < strokeSize) {
        strokeSize = getHeight() / 10;
    }
    int xCenter = (getWidth() - strokeSize) / 2;
    int yCenter = (getHeight() - strokeSize) / 2;

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, yCenter, getWidth(), strokeSize);
    g.fillRect(xCenter, 0, strokeSize, getHeight());
}
```

[image: Red Cross Picture]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're drawing the rectangles starting from the panel's center. Consequently only the right-bottom part of the cross is being drawn. Take a look to [Graphics.fillRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) javadoc:

> ```
> public abstract void fillRect(int x,
>             int y,
>             int width,
>             int height)
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>       `x` - the x coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
>       `y` - the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.
>       `width` - the width of the rectangle to be filled.
>       `height` - the height of the rectangle to be filled.

You haven't also considered the rectangles' thickness and length to center the cross properly. Your implementation should look like as follows:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int rectThickness = 10;
    int rectLength = 100;                
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(xCenter - rectLength / 2, yCenter - rectThickness / 2, rectLength, rectThickness);
    g.fillRect(xCenter - rectThickness / 2, yCenter - rectLength / 2, rectThickness, rectLength);
}
```

#### Off-topic

You should avoid the use of [setBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method and let the layout manager handle the size and positioning of the components:

```
window.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 200); // No!
```

In this case and since the panel is intended to do custom painting you can give a default size to your panel by overriding [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) method. For instance:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
}
```